# Error in package strucchange function breakpoints

Tags: r

I'm applying breakpoints function to time series, for example:

```
breakpoints(y ~ 1, h=60, breaks=5, data=portf_ret, ic='BIC', hpc='foreach')
```

where `portf_ret` is of class `xts`. Then I get following message:

```
Error in breakpoints.formula(y ~ 1, h = 60, breaks = 5, data = portf_ret_1,  :
  minimum segment size must be smaller than half the number of observations
```

The size of `portf_ret` is 1400. I have tried to plug in different hs but I still have the same message.

Does anyone know how to handle it?

I have even tried:

```
a=xts(1:100) 
breakpoints(y ~ 1,h=10,breaks=5,data=a,ic='BIC',hpc='foreach')
```

and still the same error

Unfortunately there is one more error. After naming the column I run the code and get: error in `eval(attr(terms(formula), "variables")[[2]], data, env) :`
  a numeric argument `envir` not of unit length

Does anyone know how to proceed?

Comment: Could you also share `portf_ret`?

Comment: I think I can share a piece of it. 
Do you know how to begin a chat?

Comment: https://www.dropbox.com/s/in433kpcg518zq1/portf_ret.txt?dl=0

Comment: Could you use `dput(portf_ret)` instead? It will preserve the class of `portf_ret`. However, the time serie is probably too short to be useful. And `a=xts(1:100)` doesn't work.

Comment: https://www.dropbox.com/s/i0lnj3umrbfp5ww/returns.txt?dl=0

Comment: There is no `y` in the file.

Comment: Yeah, I got it, I forgot to name a column

Comment: Could you help me with one more error?